# Close tooltip when clicking again on it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tooltip

I have created a tooltip that is opened when a button is clicked.

It should be closed when the button is clicked again but it seem to not work, it only closes when it is clicked somewhere outside.

This is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const MyClass = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleTooltipClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleTooltipOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleTooltipClose}>
        <div>
          <Tooltip
            PopperProps={{
              disablePortal: true
            }}
            onClose={handleTooltipClose}
            open={open}
            disableFocusListener
            disableHoverListener
            disableTouchListener
            title="Add">
            <Button onClick={handleTooltipOpen}>Click</Button>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default MyClass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the button should not *open* the tooltip but *toggle* it.
The button could trigger a `toggleTooltip` function

```
<Button onClick={toggleTooltip}>Click</Button>
```

and the `toggleTooltip` function would look like

```
const toggleTooltip= () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
```

which sets the `open` state to the opposite of what it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) when having a button with childs

```
const handleTooltipClose = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  setOpen(false);
};

const handleTooltipOpen = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  setOpen(true);
};
```

> The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event
> listeners calls stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(),
> either of which terminates propagation at once.

Answer (score 1):

just rewrite your `handleTooltipOpen` function a little bit like this:

```
const handleTooltipOpen = () => {
          if( open ){
            setOpen(false);
          }else{
             setOpen(true)
          }
 };
```